# Commands paths in TeXstudio on Mac OS X - with 'could not start the command' error

Tags: compiling, paths, texmaker, texstudio

When I am trying to 'quick build' my document in TeXstudio 2.1 on Mac OS X 10.6.8, I am getting and `error: could not start the command` (with 'quick build' options being LaTeX + DviPdf + PdfViewer). I know that this question has resonated across different forums:

- Latex community - [Texmaker compilation error](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=2600)
- Souceforge for TeXstudio - [Couldn't start the command (On Mac)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/texstudio/forums/forum/907839/topic/4775886),

and I realized that the key to solution is to set the right commands paths in `options > configure texstudio > commands` - the image below shows exactly how I set it up. So I set ALL command paths to `/usr/texbin/latex`, Now, the error disappears, TeXstudio starts the compilation process, but never finishes - it simply freezes in the compilation process.

I have to add I compiled the document in TeXShop and it works fine, so... it must be something I messed up with the command paths...

[image: screen capture texshop commands paths]

Comment: `/usr/texbin` is fine, but it must be followed by the right tool; for PdfLaTeX it should be `pdflatex`, for instance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Paths for a MacTeX distribution

The following settings *should* work:

```
latex       "/Library/TeX/texbin/latex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex    
dvips       "/Library/TeX/texbin/dvips" -o %.ps %.dvi
ps2pdf      "/usr/local/bin/ps2pdf" %.ps    
MakeIndex   "/Library/TeX/texbin/makeindex" %.idx    
BiBTeX      "/Library/TeX/texbin/bibtex" %.aux    
pdfLaTeX    "/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex    
dvipdf      "/Library/TeX/texbin/dvipdfm" %.dvi    
dvipng      "/Library/TeX/texbin/dvipng" -T tight -D 120 %.dvi    
Metapost    "/Library/TeX/texbin/mpost" --interaction nonstopmode     
DVI viewer  open %.dvi    
PS viewer   open %.ps    
PDF viewer  open %.pdf    
Ghostscript /usr/local/bin/gs "?am.ps"    
Asymptote   "/Library/TeX/texbin/asy" %.asy
```

If you have updated to a recent MacTeX and need to change them all at the same time, you can quit out of the app and edit the `texstudio.ini` file which is stored in `~/.config/texstudio`. This is a plain text file and you can then do a global replace of the old path with `/Library/TeX/texbin`.

### Paths for other types of distributions

If you are using any other TeX distribution, for example MacPorts or Fink, you will need to change `/usr/texbin/` to the relevant path in that particular distribution.  In MacPorts it is `/opt/local/bin/`.

I would *not* recommend using such a distribution, however, as they are generally harder to keep updated.

### Screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I've added `-synctex=1` also to the PdfLaTeX entry, which of course is missing from the screen shot, but is highly convenient.

Comment: Excellent, thank you Alan and @egreg - it works perfectly!

Comment: Thanks!! I had %.aux inside of double quote, I have changed to "/usr/texbin/bibtex" %.aux and all is ok.

Comment: my configuration is exactly what you typed up there, but still I get the error "could not start the command". I am using a newer version of TexMaker with MacTex. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: As of Os X 10.11 all paths starting with /usr/texbin/ should be changed to /Library/TeX/texbin/.

Comment: Where does this stuff go? I downloaded a latex template and tried to run it on a new OSX, gives me thes /usr/textbin/ error, but that code doesn't appear in the file. Where do I type /Library/TeX/texbin/?

Comment: @Steve Sorry this answer was out of date. The correct path should be `/Library/TeX/texbin` (replacing `/usr/texbin` in all of the settings.  This tells you how to set the settings in the preferences for TeXMaker.  The screenshot (which still shows the old paths at the moment) should help. Did you also install MacTeX?

Answer (score 5):

Note that old paths in `/usr` are not valid anymore in Os X 10.11+. All paths starting with `/usr/texbin/` should be changed to `/Library/TeX/texbin/`.

Comment: One of the nice things about Stackexchange is that everyone can edit the content. So instead of adding this as an answer, you could have just edited my original answer to reflect the change. (I've don't that now.)