# Help with installing gnuplot in MacTex and using it with LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot

I have to draw a lot of PDF and CDF graphs in my document/presentation and in order to do that I installed `gnuplot`. In order to install `gnuplot` I took the following steps:

1- Download the sources from : [gnuplot sources](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/4.4.3/gnuplot-4.4.3.tar.gz/download) then put the folder gnuplot-4.4.3 on my desktop
2- $ cd /Users/.../Desktop/gnuplot-4.4.3
3- $ ./configure --with-readline=builtin
4- $ make
5- $ sudo make install
6- test of gnuplot $ gnuplot
 gnuplot works from `Terminal`. However, I get a lot of error running the following`MWE`

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\def\cdf(#1)(#2)(#3){0.5*(1+(erf((#1-#2)/(#3*sqrt(2)))))}%
% to be used: \cdf(x)(mean)(variance)

\DeclareMathOperator{\CDF}{cdf}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$\CDF(x)$,
    grid=major]
    \addplot[smooth,red] gnuplot{\cdf(x)(0)(1)};
    \addplot[smooth,blue]gnuplot{\cdf(x)(0.5)(1)};
    \addplot[smooth,green]gnuplot{\cdf(x)(1)(1)};
    \addplot[smooth,orange]gnuplot{\cdf(x)(2)(1)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The error that I get is

`pgfplots: Sorry, the gnuplot-result file 'texstudio_DH7974.pgf-gnuplot <file>.gnuplot' manually on the respective gnuplot file.. \addlegendentryexpanded{$k = \k$}}`

or code given in [plotting chi-square](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40908/plotting-the-chi-square-distribution-with-tikz). I guess I am missing one (or maybe cuple) of steps installing gnuplot. I really appreciate if you help.

Comment: You need to run your `pdflatex` command with the `--shell-escape` option.  Can you check your TeXStudio preferences to see if that's the case?

Comment: See [Commands paths in TeXstudio on Mac OS X - with 'could not start the command' error](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38627/2693) and try adding `--shell-escape` to the line for `pdflatex`.

Comment: Thanks a million @AlanMunn: It works beautifully! For the future reference, in TexStudio preferences, under Commands, PdfLaTeX is `/usr/texbin/pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex`. Again, THANK YOU!

Comment: @AlanMunn: Can you please turn this into an answer, then I can accept it? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you can run `gnuplot` from the Terminal, you have installed it correctly. But you also need to configure `pdflatex` to allow it to run external programs. Since you are using TeXStudio you need to go into its preferences and change the entry for `pdflatex`.  See

- [Commands paths in TeXstudio on Mac OS X - with 'could not start the command' error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38627/2693)

for details on this.  So the correct line to allow you to run `gnuplot` from within a LaTeX document is:

```
 pdfLaTeX    "/usr/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex
```

Comment: Well, I'm in a very similar situation, and this command doesn't work for me. I have Mountain Lion 10.8.2, with TeXworks, TeXShop and TextMate. I installed gnuplot from MacPorts (and it works from the terminal). If I call it from any of those three programs it gives me an error (and I have to manually execute gnuplot from the terminal). I don't know what happens (it worked well in Snow Leopard).

Comment: @Manuel This sounds like a path problem.  Do you get the same error as above, or something different?

Comment: `Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the gnuplot-result file 'untitled.pgf-plot.table' could not be found. Maybe you need to enable the shell-escape feature? For pdflatex, this is '>> pdflatex -shell-escape'. You can also invoke '>> gnuplot .gnuplot' manually on the respective gnuplot file.` How can I solve that PATH problem (it's true, TextMate usually asks to set PATH, but this time it didn't).